# Error: Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::save does not exist

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-8

estoy haciendo una vista para configuraciones de mi web. estas configuraciones van dentro
de una tabla. el problema es que no me deja hacer el update.
Error:

**Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::save does not exist.**

base de datos:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ij0t0.png

```
public function config(Request $request){
    $data = [
        'category_name' => 'forms',
        'page_name' => 'layouts',
        'has_scrollspy' => 1,
        'scrollspy_offset' => 100

            ];

   $config = Configuraciones::All();
   if ($request->isMethod('put')) {
    $config->mantenimiento = $request->mantenimiento;
    $config->cierre = $request->cierre;
    $config->instagram = $request->instagram;
    $config->facebook = $request->facebook;
    $config->whatsapp = $request->whatsapp;
    $config->telefono = $request->telefono;
    $config->registro = $request->registro;
    $config->save();
}
    // $pageName = 'contacts';
    return view('configuraciones',compact('config'))->with($data);
}
```

Rutas:

```
    Route::get('configuraciones','SistemaController@config')->name('configuraciones');
Route::put('configuraciones', 'SistemaController@config' )->name('uconfig');
```

Como puedo actualizar los datos en la tabla?

Comment: ¿Te das cuenta que quieres actualizar una colección y no un solo objeto? Tu consulta de config no busca una configuración en específico. Al hacer all, estás consultando todas las filas de la tabla Configuraciones.

Comment: Como puedo actualizar sin hacer :All y sin tener un id de indice?

Comment: esa es mi duda, saber si había forma de hacerlo sin un identificador de fila

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En esta línea:

```
$config = Configuraciones::All();
```

- Obtienes de vuelta todos los registros de la tabla, en este caso de *`configuraciones`*.
- Entonces es razonable el error pues sobre esa clase colección de la cual es instancia no existe el método `save`
- Por cierto, el nombre del método es [**`all()`**](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#retrieving-models) en minúsculas, *atención a eso*

Por otro lado mencionas en los comentarios que no se tiene un id (que sería la *pk*), entonces tu consulta se puede tratar de esta forma:

```
$config = Configuraciones::where('clave', $valor)->first(); 

    $config->mantenimiento = $request->mantenimiento;
    $config->cierre = $request->cierre;
    $config->instagram = $request->instagram;
    $config->facebook = $request->facebook;
    $config->whatsapp = $request->whatsapp;
    $config->telefono = $request->telefono;
    $config->registro = $request->registro;
    $config->save();
```

Debes considerar lo siguiente:

- Filtramos entonces por medio del método `where` para encontrar aquel registro a actualizar
- Atención que se puede dar el caso de que si no filtras por la pk entonces mas de un valor pudiera responder a la condición establecida en el `where`, entonces puedes emplear el método [`first`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#retrieving-single-models) para quedarte con el primero encontrado

  - Ahora si quieres retornar una excepción si no se encuentra algún modelo que cumpla las condiciones dadas puedes usar [`firstOrFail`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#not-found-exceptions)
- Ya si necesitas que la actualización trabaje sobre varios registros en lugar de solo uno entonces puedes realizarlo de [*forma masiva*](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#mass-updates)